# Unable to Create Notification channel in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a notification message when clicking the Start Button, but there's nothing in notification center after clicking the button, any ideas ?

Testing on Android 14 with IDEA.

https://github.com/speedyHKjournalist/MapleServerAndroid/blob/e51a1177050b9fa120edbe0ef77180115e987c32/app/src/main/java/com/mapleserver/ServerService.kt#L21

```
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val channelId = intent?.getStringExtra("channel_id") ?: "default_id"
        val pendingIntent = intent?.getParcelableExtra("pending_intent", PendingIntent::class.java)
        val initializationThread = Thread {
            val args = arrayOf("-Xmx2048m", "-Dwz-path=wz", "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true")
            Server.getInstance(applicationContext)
            Server.main(args)
        }
        initializationThread.start()

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(ComponentActivity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, "OpenMapleServer Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "1")
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("OpenMapleServer Notification")
            .setContentText("OpenMapleServer is Running")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setChannelId("1")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        val notification = builder.build()
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
        startForeground(startId, notification)
        return START_STICKY
    }
```

Comment: Android 13 revamped notification permissions: Are you sure you and your app are permitted to send notifications? See https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission

Comment: Yes, permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/> has been already added.

Comment: Ah, thanks, it's a dumb question, I forgot to allow notification for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since comments can't be marked as answer i copied my comment to an answer:

Android 13 revamped notification permissions: Are you sure you and your app are permitted to send notifications? See https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission